# Does BigQuery still pull from cache if I add a comment to the query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I run a query like

```
SELECT field
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If I run this same query again, BigQuery will pull it from the cache, which means it will not cost any processing.

If I add a comment (which does not actually change the query contents) does it still pull the results from cache? Such as below

```
SELECT field
# some comment about the query
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 2):

The addition of the comment will invalidate the cache and BigQuery will process the data once again. Any change at all to the query text will do this, regardless of whether it changes the actual query that runs.

Comment: I would add to your own answer that you can check the use of the cache in this following two ways: GCP Console or BigQuery API. You can see more detailed info in GCP documentation related to ["Using cached query results"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#verifying_use_of_the_cache)

Comment: Even a single space will invalidate the query. At the moment, BigQuery checks string equivalence.